# how to store the result of the request in table

Tags: android, sqlite

hi
I want to store the result of request in a table. I want the result of the method is table howa to do that? My code contains error.

```
public array getResult_libelle(int id)
    {
        array tab[] = null;
        try
        {
            Cursor c = null;
            c = db.rawQuery("select libelle from favori where _id="+id, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            tab = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("libelle"));
            c.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tab; 
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error output from LogCat

Comment: It's not a problem when i run the application it is errors in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ArrayList <String> getResult_libelle(int id)
{
    ArrayList <String> tab = new ArrayList <Stringr>();
    try
    {
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select libelle from favori where _id="+id, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
          tab.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("libelle")));
          c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tab; 
}
```

Comment: I have problem with put and moveToNext

Comment: code corrected (add instad of put, ArrayList instead of List), but don't see any problem with c.moveToNext();

Comment: I change c.moveToNext(); to  c.getCount();

Comment: I don't think that thil will work with more tan one entry, you will alwas get the same result (the first one) Can't imagin what the problem withe the moveToNext() schould be...

Comment: yes you are right, I change to c.moveToNext(); I don't have any problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your cursor will already be having only the column named `libelle` so I don't think there should be a need to explicitly filter it out.

I guess, you should directly use `getString(i)` to get data of each row out, one by one, from the cursor

give that a try.